# CSS background-color of table header of inner table?

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<table id="t1">
  <th>test</th>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table id="t2">
          <th>test2</th>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS for different background-color of "test2"?:

```
#t1 tr td #t2 th{
  background-color: ~;
}
```

Comment: I don't get it, what is the question???

Comment: how to acheive this?: #t1 tr td #t2 th{
  background-color: ~;
}

Comment: th or td can only be childs of tr :(  tr is missing here

Comment: @GCyrillus —  Nothing is missing, the code in the question is using descendant combinators, not child combinator.

Comment: @faalbane — Aside from `~` not being a colour, the code you have looks right (aside from nested tables being a strong indicator that you shouldn't be using tables at all). What problem do you have?

Comment: @Quentin <table> <th> seems right to you ? where is at least tr ? code is not valid but selector will look for it !

Comment: @GCyrillus — I thought you were talking about the selector syntax. (Error recovery means that code will still "work" though, so it is still hard to tell what problem the OP is having).

Comment: My original code works ... I had a attribute naming error (now fixed) ... thanks for you help ...

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
#t2 th{
    background-color: ~;
}
```

Comment: They can, but they can use the code they already have too. So what problem does this solve?

Comment: My original code works ... I had a attribute naming error (now fixed) ... thanks for you help ...